# Expectation by conditioning on an event (recursions)

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, recursion

My problem goes as follows : Consider $X_n$, where $n\geq1$, as the sequence of independent poisson r.v's with mean 5. Further, we define

$N$ = min{$n\geq3$ : $X_{n-2}=2$, $X_{n-1}=1$, $X_n$=0}

and our goal is the find $E(N)$ (i.e, the expectation of the number of trials it takes to get the ordered sequence {2,1,0}. Here is my approach:

---

I first started by defining two complementing events, $M$ and $L$, where (written informally):

$M$ = first time that {2,1} appears in the sequence, and
$L$ = first time that {2} appears in the sequence,

This follows that

$E(N)$ = $E(E(N|M))$
= $E[P(X=0)(E(N|\text{next in seq. is 0}) + P(X\neq0)(E(N|\text{next in seq. not 0}))]$

$=E[(e^{-5}(E(M))+1) + (1-e^{-5})(E(M)+1+E(N))]$

$=E(M)e^{5}+e^{5}$

(first thing I'm unsure of is the case where $X\neq0$. Does the $E(N)$ encompass the +1 already in the case where the counter restarts?)

We can then create an equation for $E(M)$:

$E(M)$ = $E[P(X=1)(E(M|\text{next in seq. is 1}) + P(X\neq1)(E(M|\text{next in seq. not 1}))]$

=$E[5e^{-5}(E(L)+1) + (1-5e^{-5})(E(L)+1+E(M))]$

=$e^{5}/5 +(e^{5}/5)E(L)$

and since now we only need to look for $X=2$, $L$ follows a geometric with $p = P(X=2)$, thus we can solve for $E(M)$ and then $E(N)$.

Now the answer that this gives is not the answer provided in the textbook : $\frac{1}{e^{-5}5e^{-5}5^{2}e^{-5}/2!}$.

I'm not sure where my logic is flawed or if my approach is overall faulty. Additionally, notation for the double expectation is also irking me. I just end up dropping the second expectation without really knowing why (some clarification would be much appreciated).

Comment: The answer "provided in the textbook" is incorrect, was there an error in your typing it? What answer did you get?

Comment: @Math1000 The answer I get with the method showed above is E(N) = (e^10)/5+(e^5)+(e^15)*2/(5^3) or approx = 56857.98428.... Now again I'm unsure of adding the +1 when doing E(N|next in seq is not 0) or E(M|next in seq is not 1). removing the 1 from those (assuming the recursion covers the +1), yields a similar answer of E(N) = (2/125)*(e^15)+(e^5)+1 or approx = 52453.69112...

Comment: @Math1000 Also this solution is from the solution manual to "introduction to probability models" from Ross. It does however have a few faulted answers so I wouldn't be surprised if the textbook is wrong. I tried simulating this expectation using R but unfortunately to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach of solving a system of linear equations to determine the mean absorption time in a Markov chain can be applied here. Let $\tau_i$ be the expected number of trials remaining to observe $\{2,1,0\}$ given that the past $i$ trials are of this sequence, for $i=0,1,2$, then from  $\tau_i = 1+\sum_{j\in\{0,1,2\}}P_{ij}\tau_j $ we have the equations
\begin{align}
\tau_0&=1+\left(1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^2\right) \tau_0+ \frac{1}{2} e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^2 \tau_1\\
\tau _1&=1+ \left(-\frac{1}{2} e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^2-e^{-\lambda } \lambda +1\right) \tau _0+\frac{1}{2} e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^2 \tau _1+e^{-\lambda } \lambda  \tau _2\\
\tau_2&=1+\left(1-e^{-\lambda }\right) \tau_0.
\end{align}
Solving yields $\tau_0=e^\lambda+2\lambda^{-3}e^{3\lambda}$, and for $\lambda=5$, this is approximately $52452.69112$.

Comment: I could be mistaken but is there an extra +1 in the third equation (t2)?

Comment: @Alex03 Indeed, it was an error in transcribing my work. Thanks for pointing it out.